# SQL Query is being print 4 times , in monitor session (where we see locks on DB Objects)

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate

I am using Hibernate as Entity Framework and Oracle for backend , when I run a particular Update Query, It gets stuck and when i see the same in lock objects (in monitor session in SQL developer), at there it was being print 4 times. I haven't use any parallel or parallel(4).

Comment: Does the query reference any GV$ table?  If you're using Real Application Clusters (RAC) then some data dictionary queries will implicitly run in parallel to get data from each node.

Comment: I am using permanent table for the same (not any global volatile), but still getting the same issue.